# ElasticSearch with river to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have installed and configured MongoDB and ES with mongodb river. But I'm not sure if I really understand rivers in ES. For example, I want index collection "users" from mongodb.

I will send curl PUT/POST request to url /_river/mongodb_users/_meta

```
{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": {
    "db": "somedb",
    "collection": "users"
  },
  "index": {
    "name": "users",
    "type": "user"
  }
}
```

But now, I want to index second collection, for example "users2". I really need to create new river using curl POST/PUT on url like /_river/mongodb_users2/_meta with JSON:

```
{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": {
    "db": "somedb",
    "collection": "users2"
  },
  "index": {
    "name": "users2",
    "type": "user"
  }
}
```

I can not use already created river "mongodb_users"? I will need create one river for one collection?

Thank you for explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The way MongoDB river works does not allow to fetch content from more than one collection in a single river.

But, you can create as many river as you need.

That said, if you want to index users1 to users type in Elasticsearch and users2 to the same users type, you can (as soon as they don't use the same IDs).

Just modify `index.type` to `"users"`.

Does it help?